# why background image is not displaying in this simple code?

Tags: html, css, display

Not displaying background image in class i am trying by giving exact path of image and also by placing it's name

```
.sat{
 height:auto;
 width:auto;
background-image:url(C:\Users\MHC\Desktop\ggg.png); 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  </head>
<body>
<div class="sat"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try double slashes:  C:\\Users\\MHC\\Desktop\\ggg.png

Answer (score 1):

Please give some height to your div for example

```
.sat{
background-image:url(C:\Users\MHC\Desktop\ggg.png); 
heigh:250px;
width:150px;
}
```

Comment: Better if the path is relative and not absolute to hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an empty element, `height:auto;` is 0, therefore you should specify a height and a width to the element

Comment: Did you even try before downvoting?

Comment: if you put a color as background can you see it? if so you should try other way to call the image.

Comment: yeah i am able to see

Comment: so if put the image in the same directory as the html and call it relatively it should work. If you need the whole route as you put I believe you shouldn't use backslashes, try to change them for normal slashes `C://Users/MHC/Desktop/ggg.png`

Answer (score 0):

**Point:1**
Why you are using local file system?

It seems you can provide just the local image name, assuming it is in the same folder.

```
background-image:url("ggg.png");//put image same folder of your file
```

If you still want to use local file system then try it:

```
background-image:url("file:///C:/Users/MHC/Desktop/ggg.png");
```

**Point:2**
Your 'div' still empty because **background properties** can not contain any **height** or **width**.

> So you have to put **content** or you have to use **height** and **width** to
>   consume space.

So use:

```
<div class="sat">**Put any content**</div>
```

**or**

```
.sat {
  background-image:url("ggg.png"); 
  width: 100px; // your custom height
  height: 100px; // your custom width
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
background-image:url("C:\Users\MHC\Desktop\ggg.png");
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you give some more info about what server are you using ?

You can ofcorse try.

```
body {
    background: url("file:///C:/Users/MHC/Desktop/ggg.png");
}
```